# QQ plot distribution check

Tags: data-visualization, lognormal-distribution, qq-plot, exploratory-data-analysis, distribution-identification

I want to check if a distribution is log normal or not by using qq plot. So for convenience I am creating a 
lognormal distribution using `stats` and checking it in probplot by using the dist function. But still I am not getting my points on 45 degree line i.e the qq plot showing my z is not lognormal. Why?I am new here any help would be much appreciated. Here my code

```
z=stats.lognorm.rvs(2.5,size=500)
stats.probplot(z,dist=stats.lognorm, sparams=(2.5,),plot=pylab)
pylab.show()
```

and this is my result: [image: Probability plot]

Comment: Showing a Normal probability plot of the logarithms would provide more insight by revealing what is going on among the lower 98% of the data.

Comment: sorry i couldnot get you.My question was using qq plot it should have given a straight 45 degree line but here the points deviated even though both x and y are log normal.Why is that?

Comment: There will always be some deviations. The main problem with your plot is the scaling - the majority of observations lie at the bottom left of the figure so we cannot really seen what is going on there, hence @whuber asking to change to logs

Comment: ok!!now i see.i had similar issues with other qq plots too like that of pareto or loggamma for the same reason.Thanks a lot!!!